# Identity Server 4 - Monitoring of expiring credentials in ClientCredentials flow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

SSO build on:
.NET Core 3.1,
ASP.NET MVC,
Identity Server 4,
PostreSQL

We have created separate API with which the clients of our SSO can route their credentials (client_id, client_secret) with a mandatory expiration date. Now we need to start watching when they expire and if they have a few days left to let them know.

We have to somehow hook up to the authorization flow and intercept. To take a client and a secret and do some business logic. But we can't find a suitable place for that.

We also need access to ClientStore cache so that we do not make unnecessary SQL request.

Middleware /
Override of one of the classes /
Event /

Some tips :)

Thanks

Comment: Your current thinking is to obtain this credential and then determine when it will expire?

Comment: Yes, and after I know when it expires, if it is less than a week, for example, to send an event to the user.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.